# Synonyms for кстати

Tags: синонимы

What are commonly used, synonymous words and phrases for **`кстати`**?

I mean also in the sense of `now that I think about it` (`мне приходит голову`?).

Comment: I used "BTW" when chatting and translating "кстати" in English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`Кстати`** has two meanings: as in `just when it was needed` [example: мне нужна была информация, и эта статья попалась мне очень кстати - I needed information, and I saw this article just when it was needed], and as in `apropos` or `by the way` [example: кстати, ты читал эту книгу? - By the way, have you read this book?].

Synonymous words in first case can be: как раз (exactly at/when/as...; note that this phrase can't be used as a finishing phrase to a sentence, it must be followed by some description: как раз когда нужно, как раз где хотел, как раз как понадобилось etc...), вовремя (on the right time), своевременно (in a timely manner), к месту (in place), на руку (in hand), в нужный момент (on the right time/on the right moment)...

Synonymous words in second case: к слову (speaking of/by the way), говоря о [...] (speaking of [...]), кстати о птичках (speaking of birds - used jokingly, not to be used in formal conversations, just among friends), между прочим (by the way/among other things), апропо (apropos - extremely rarely used).

Answer (score -1):

All words bellow are synonymous:

уместно, у места, к месту, к лицу, на руку, с руки, к слову, в лад, в меру, впору, в самую пору, впопад, вовремя, в (свое, надлежащее) время, своевременно, благовременно, во благовременьи, под стать, соразмерно, пропорционально, как раз, мимоходом; подходящий; в нужный момент, пользуясь случаем, ко времени, кстати о музыке, тут же, в свое время, кстати замечу, между делом, при случае, замечу кстати, к слову сказать, попутно, попутно замечу, между прочим, благовремение, на ходу, заодно, к руке, кстати сказать, замечу попутно.

Comment: rocketq, it'd be more helpful to have only some mentioned, but therefore a short note about the `оттенки значения` and how commonly it is used.

Comment: This answer is of very low quality. Not all words are synonyms of the meaning that embert mentioned ("к лицу", "на руку", etc.), not all words are commonly used ("замечу попутно", "во благовременьи", etc.), not all words can be used in the same context ("на ходу") or grammatical position ("подходящий").

Comment: But the question was also quite of a low quality, he asked syn. and I have provided it.